# Copy PostgreSQL database from server to localhost

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump

I am pretty new to PostgreSQL and not quite sure how to manage this.
What I am trying to do is to copy an existing database from a server to localhost or another server, that does not matter as long as it is another host.

I tried to to this via PgAdmin, but I dont see a possibility to easily copy it via the GUI. The next thing I did was to try

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

but I got some connection issues.

I would be very thankful if someone could list up the steps I have to take in order to reach that goal, considerung I dont have any experience in postgres.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `pgAdmin` [Backup/Restore](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.15/backup_and_restore.html). Postgres client programs [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) and to dump the global objects from [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) `pg_dumpall -g`.

Answer (score 0):

To copy your database you can run the commands below.

To create a new backup from your server:

```
$ pg_dump -h server -U username mydatabase > db.sql
```

To restore the created backup in your local database:

```
$ psql -d newdatabase -f db.sql
```

Another option is to use *pg_basebackup*, which is a physical backup.

To create a backup of the remote server with one compressed tar file for each tablespace, and store it in the directory backup, showing a progress report while running:

```
$ pg_basebackup -h remoteServer -D backup -Ft -z -P
```